# Atlas текстуры для Android

Tags: java, android

у меня в приложении есть атлас с расширением .plist, подскажите пожалуйста в чем он был сделан? И можно ли его обратно как то распаковать и получить отдельные изображения?

Comment: В .plist хранятся различные параметры в виде <key>Ключ</key><string>Значение</string>, но никак не изображения. Можно открыть в программе XCode или любым текстовым редактором, если в вашем файле данные сохранены в текстовом виде

Comment: Да я немного не верно выразился, с ним еще лежит файл png, в нем уже собраны все перечисленные в файле Plist изображения. Можно ли как то их отдельно получить? Так как мне нужно отредактировать только несколько изображений в этом атласе, но у меня нет исходников.

Comment: Советую воспользоваться программой Blender

Comment: Спасибо, а в каком приложении потом можно будет заново создать атлас с расширением plist?